# Encode and Decode - JPG to base64

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-upload, base64, decoding

I'm developing a Windows Phone Application which uploads a user selected photo to a server using PHP.
For this, I'm trying to convert the image to base64 and POST it to PHP where it is decoded back to JPG image.

The base64 string is successfully posted to the PHP but I always get a corrupted JPG file instead of the original image at the server (meaning that there is some error in encoding/decoding of the image).

The C# code for Application is:

```
public partial class SamplePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public SamplePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;

        private void SampleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
            selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
            selectphoto.Show();
        }

        void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
                txtBX.Text = e.OriginalFileName;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://"+QR_Reader.MainPage.txtBlck+"/beamer/saveimage.php");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                Stream photoStream = ImageToStream(image1);
                BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage();
                bimg.SetSource(photoStream); //photoStream is a stream containing data for a photo

                byte[] bytearray = null;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bimg);
                    wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbitmp.PixelWidth, wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    bytearray = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
                string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);

                string postData = String.Format("image={0}", str);   

                // Getting the request stream.
                request.BeginGetRequestStream
                (result =>
                {
                    // Sending the request.
                    using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(postData);
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
                    }

                    // Getting the response.
                    request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                    {
                        var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                        using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                            {
                                string srresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);
                }, null);

            }  // end of taskresult == OK           
        }  // end of select photo completed

        private Stream ImageToStream(Image image1)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);

            wb.Render(image1, new TranslateTransform { X = 400, Y = 400 });

            wb.Invalidate();
            Stream myStream = new MemoryStream();

            wb.SaveJpeg(myStream, 400, 400, 0, 70);

            return myStream;
        }
    }  // End of Class
```

The PHP code at the server to decode and save image is:

```
<?php
function base64_to_image( $imageData, $outputfile ) {
    // encode & write data (binary)
    $ifp = fopen( $outputfile, "wb" );

    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $imageData ) );
    fclose( $ifp );
    // return output filename 
    return( $outputfile );
}       

if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
    base64_to_image($_POST['image'], "img.jpg");
}
else
    die("no image data found");
?>
```

I don't know what is wrong here.
I've been searching for hours to do this and I'm still failing.

Please help me.

**EDIT:**
I just figured out that I always get the same base64 string irrespective of any image that I choose.
This is what is get after base64 conversion:
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=vWZy

I am really puzzled now. I'm getting the same output for each and very image.
I don't know why this is happening.

I really want to do this, and I'm stuck here, at base64 encoding.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be *all* of the problem, but this code is broken:

```
byte[] bytearray = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bimg);
    wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbitmp.PixelWidth, wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bytearray = ms.GetBuffer();
}
```

By using `GetBuffer`, you'll get the underlying buffer which may well be bigger than the *real* data. You can use `ToArray` instead - and you don't need to "rewind" the stream before using either `GetBuffer` or `ToArray`:

```
byte[] bytearray = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bimg);
    wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbitmp.PixelWidth, wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    bytearray = ms.ToArray();
}
```

If that doesn't work, you should take a close look at the before and after files, ideally in a binary file editor:

- Do they have the same size?
- Where do they differ, and how? Is there any pattern?

Comment: Thanks! I've made the correction as you pointed out. But, still the encoding is having problems in it. I've ensured everything else, including the decoding at PHP, everything is working fine except for the base64 encoding.

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma: But you've still given no indication of exactly what's wrong. How can you know that the decoding is successful if you can't get the encoding working? How do you know it's not the decoding that fails? What does the file look like afterwards? Without more information we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: See, I decoded the image online at: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ and then decoded it with the above PHP script and it worked perfectly. This means that decoding is working perfectly.

Further, the encoding results from my C# Application and the link above were different.
This clearly means that there is some problem in base64 encoding in C#. Please help me.

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma: Well your C# app is rewriting the image as a JPEG. So I'd quite possibly expect the results to be different. You should write out the results *not* in base64 to a file, within your C# code. Then encode that in base64, and perform similar diagnostics. Basically there's a whole host of things that you can do, which we can't.

Comment: Hey, I seriously think that the function private Stream ImageToStream(Image image1) has the problem.

I don't know because I just found it somewhere and I tried to use it in my code. Also, I have no idea why:
 WriteableBitmap(400, 400);
is used, I mean why dimensions are restricted to 400x400.
Can you help me on this?

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma: No - you need to do some diagnosis for yourself. To be honest, this is what you get when you grab random code from the net and don't check whether it does what's required. My guess is that in the original context, 400x400 was appropriate. *Maybe* you can just change that code for your purposes... but you need to work to understand it first.

Comment: Lol.
By the way, I'm not that type of a guy. I always write my code myself.
But, seriously, this time I had no idea on how to do it. So, it took a leap of faith.

Well, I'll carry on anyway.

Comment: @ShrayanshSharma: I very strongly suspect the problem *isn't* in the base64 encoding part at all. It's in the data that you're encoding. As I've already suggested, you should save the stream to disk and see whether that's the image you expect - I bet it isn't. I wouldn't be at all surprised if the problem is in the code that you took directly from another site.